# SVN ignore *.jpg not working?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I'm trying to  ignore .jpg but it is not working.

I write the command for

> svn propset svn:ignore *.jpg

I want to ignore jpg file.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: yes i know. I am asking how to ignore .jpg files

Comment: @unwind No, but according to the FAQ, it probably falls under `practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession`

Comment: @r.vengadesh Are you looking to ignore them in a specific directory only, or recursively below a directory?

Comment: no i want to ignore all .jpg files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want it ignored in just a single repository, in that case @borrible's answer is the correct one. Just in case you want an alternative, if you want .jpg files ignored *globally*, you can do it in the file

```
~/.subversion/config
```

In that file, you can add the value to `global-ignores`;

```
global-ignores = *.jpg
```

Comment: @r.vengadesh Did you remove the `#` comment at the start of the global-ignores line? Also, the ignore should be `*.jpg`, not `.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the `*.jpg` part of your command otherwise your shell will expand it before it gets passed to `svn`, add a path and get it to recurse to your subdirectories if necessary.

```
svn propset -R svn:ignore "*.jpg" .
```

Comment: I've updated with a note on recursing to subdirectories, should that be your specific issue.

Comment: Note that only directories already added to SVN will get the property, all new directories need to have it set again.

Comment: In my project .jpg files are in Images->upload folder.Then how to enter svn command?

Comment: If the Images/upload directory has already been added to svn, `cd Images; cd upload; svn propset svn:ignore "*.jpg" .`